# Office 2007: .xls file opens excel with no workbook. "Ignore other apps that use DDE" already unchecked

Tags: microsoft-excel

Auto-recover failed to save a workbook I had open. I've tried to recover the wkbook by going to the auto-recover folder - found a .xlb file there, converted it to .xls. It is now opening excel, but no workbook. Any ideas on how to get into this xlb / xls file?

already tried the often cited solution of unchecking “Ignore other apps that use DDE”.

Comment: IF there is no personal data in that damaged file, would you mind to [share it with us](http://ge.tt/) for fiddling around with it?

Answer (score 0):

check to make sure that the spreadsheet isn't outside the viewable area.

On the View Menu, look for Arrange All:
[image: view menu]

Select *tiled* or *cascade*, and you should then see the missing worksheets

Comment: While a good idea, this did not work. No worksheet is opened to cascade/tile.